# How to fetch multiple records from filemaker pro

Tags: filemaker

table contain 1304 records but after running the script given below it shows only the last record 1304 times. so please help me.is it possible to fetch multiple records from filemaker,i dont have any idea.

```
<?php include ("dbaccess.php");?>
<?php
//Create the 'find all' command and specify the layout
$findCommand = $fm->newFindAllCommand('eventsROY');
//Perform the find and store the result
$result = $findCommand->execute();

        //Check for an error
        if (FileMaker::isError($result)) {
            echo "<p>Error: " . $result->getMessage() . "</p>";
            exit;
        }
   //Store the matching records
        $records = $result->getRecords();
//print_r($records);
        echo $cnt =  count($records);
    foreach($records as $rc){

       $time = $rc->getField('time');echo "<pre>";
print_r($time);
echo "<pre>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This question is super old so I'm not sure if it's still an issue, but if it is maybe I can help.

What do the fields look like on your layout `eventsROY` layout? More importantly, are they all coming from the layout's native Table Occurrence or are some of them, `time` specifically, coming from a different related table?

Your structure is correct. I cleaned it up a little here:

```
<?php 
include ("dbaccess.php");

//Create the 'find all' command and specify the layout
$findCommand = $fm->newFindAllCommand('eventsROY');

//Perform the find and store the result
$result = $findCommand->execute();

//Check for an error
if (FileMaker::isError($result)) {
    echo "<p>Error: " . $result->getMessage() . "</p>";
    exit;
}

//Store the matching records
echo $count = $result->getFetchCount();

foreach($result->getRecords() as $record){

    $time = $record->getField('time');

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($time);
    echo "<pre>";
}

?>
```

So, if you're getting the record count you expect from the `eventsROY` table, it means that the query is working and if you're getting a value (even if it's wrong) from the time field it means that field is available on the `eventsROY` layout.

The way I could see this pulling the same `time` value over and over is if time is a field from a related table and the relationship for that related table using the same related record for every record in your `eventsROY` table. For example, if you had a table called `schedule` that was related to the `eventsROY` table by a cartesian join (`X`) then when you look at the `schedule::time` field from any `eventsROY` record the value would be the same because it's using the **first** related record from the `schedule` table to show the value.

What you should do to troubleshoot this is:

- Go to your `eventsROY` layout in FileMaker and see if the `time` field is coming from the `eventsROY`table or a different related table
- If it is coming from the `eventsROY` table and is a calculation, make sure the calculation is being Evaluated from the `eventsROY` table occurrence (if it's being evaluated from a different TO that could cause an issue too)
- Back in your php, try using a `print_r($record)` in place of your `print_r($time)` just to make sure that the rest of your fields are also returning the expected response